# Swift crashing on CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() line with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cllocationmanager

My app is crashing on this line:

```
if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse {
```

with this error:

```
EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

I have no idea what I could be doing wrong. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

*When in Use* authorization paradigm is available starting from iOS 8.

Apple docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/requestWhenInUseAuthorization

So the crash may be caused by calling `AuthorizedWhenInUse`instance on iOS 7. To prevent it, you have to check API availability